# Why so many kernel updates lately?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, kernel

The last two kernel updates have had a kernel pushed out followed by an updated kernel literally the next day.  What's going on with this?  And is this likely to continue, i.e. should we start waiting for a week or so after a kernel comes out to prevent wasted effort from installing the one that will be immediately replaced?

Comment: I don't see how the update method is germane.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with that update ? 
Maybe there was an issue, so Canonical may have patched it later updates.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Ubuntu kernels are updated every 3 weeks for stable releases. However; in cases of critical CVE fixes or regressions updates may be pushed out in a shorter span than those 3 weeks. Overall that quick of an update should be an exception. If you'd like more information about what the updates fix you can always look in the changelog of the package.